# Select 2: How to create an option which already exists in the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select with `tags:true, multiple`, populated from a database. Now new option can be created only if it is not already exists in the list. Created option is first in the list [new option while not exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBd7V.png) But I can't create option with the same text [which is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIkza.png)

How could I achieve this?

**Updated**: link to the tagging documentation https://select2.org/tagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set value, and then it works:

```
var lastId = $(".selectExample option").length + 1
var newState = new Option('Orange', lastId, true, true);
$(".selectExample").append(newState).trigger('change');
```

See full example in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/phnk05od/9/#&togetherjs=sfjozzpr9N

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is it possible to set the value on the fly? Not on the button click but on typing it in the input? As I understand from the documentation https://select2.org/tagging , now it sets it but only if the value is unique. I would like to set it even if the text already exists.